# Update ImageView's bitmap using UI-Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-imageview, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

I have to manipulate pixels of a bitmap every one second, during another operation, and show the result in `ImageView`. This is a method that manipulates bitmap and updates `ImageView`:

```
private void overlay(Bitmap bitmap) {
int j = 70;
while (flag) {
    //here I manipulate some pixels of bitmap that corresponds to "j" 
    //and save result in "tempBmp":
    ...
    //update imageView:
    iv1.setImageBitmap(tempBmp);
    iv1.postInvalidate();
    //          try {
    //              Thread.sleep(1000);
    //          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //          }
    //update "j":
    j = (j+1)%src.rows();
}
}
```

Above method is called from UI thread (`onclick` event of button) in this way:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        overlay(bmp);
    }
});
```

When App is running, there is no problem, App crash or ANR, but the `ImageView` (`iv1`) does not update. I debug the code and  bitmap's pixels are manipulating. Also I uncomment `try/catch` block, but the result was the same.

It is strange: when I comment start and end of while block, bitmap manipulate correctly (one time and for `j = 70`) and the `ImageView` updates as expected!

***Update question:***

With respect to comments and answers of eshayne and Onik I changed pixel manipulation in `overlay` method to a simple operation and check the result, but result was the same. Real `overlay` method use `openCV` but here I change color of pixels, so you can see result without using `openCV`:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                overlay(bmp);
            }
        }).run();
    }
});
```

**overlay method,simplified:**

```
private void overlay(Bitmap bitmap){
    int j = 0;
    tempBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
    while (j < bitmap.getHeight()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
            tempBmp.setPixel(i, j, 0);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // post the changes to Ui thread
        iv1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                iv1.setImageBitmap(tempBmp);
            }
        });
        j = (j + 1);
    }

}
```

How can I update `ImageView`, every second with `while`? Did I do any thing wrong?

Comment: I can't see any thread but the main thread

Comment: @blackbelt OK!but why imageview does not update?

Comment: I can't see where you are modifying the bitmap either

Comment: @blackbelt Bitmap manipulate in `while` block,after second line,that I added as comment : `here I manipulate some pixels of bitmap that corresponds to "j" ...`

Comment: You should be doing all your manipulation off of the main thread, and only using the UI thread to redraw the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your loop outside of the UI thread, then just run the setImageBitmap call within the UI thread. Something like:

```
// from non-UI thread:
while (flag) {
    // perform image manipulation
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            iv1.setImageBitmap(tempBmp);
        }
    });
}
```